# how to get ID value from looped table using php and javascript

Tags: php, jquery

I've been trying to work out how to create a table using php and mysql, this is what i've got so far...

PHP :-

```
foreach($result as $res){
        echo '<tr><td style="display:none;"><p id="ID">' . $ID . ' </p></td><td>' . $res['NAME'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $res['option2'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $res['Option3'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $res['Option4'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $res['Option5'] . '</td>
        <td class="deleteBtn"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="deleteBtn">Delete</button></td></tr>';
    }
```

Javascript:-

```
$('button#deleteBtn').click( function(){

data = $('p#ID').html();
alert(data);

// window.location('admin.php?link=LF1'+data);
});
```

when i click deleteBtn i want to delete the row the button is on, therefore i need the ID... 
How do I get the value of $ID. my jquery alerts only the first ID for every button...

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot use `<p id="ID">` in a loop.  The `id` attribute must be unique across the DOM, but you will wind up with a stack of `<p>` tags all with the same id.  You have to append another value to the `id` attribute, or use a class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `id` should be unique, so you cannot do `id="ID"` for every row.

Try with:

```
foreach($result as $res){
  echo '<tr data-id="' . $ID . '">';
    // ...
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

And in JavaScript:

```
$('button#deleteBtn').click( function(){
  var id = $(this).parents('tr').data('id');
  alert(id);
}
```

Comment: I tried all of them but this one was the easiest to get my head around!! thanks for the ninja response!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data` attribute to keep your id. like `data-id="1"`

```
foreach($result as $res) {
        echo '<tr><td style="display:none;"><p data-id="'.$ID.'" id="ID"'.$ID.' data-id="">' . $ID . ' </p></td><td>' . $res['NAME'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $res['option2'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $res['Option3'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $res['Option4'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $res['Option5'] . '</td>
        <td class="deleteBtn"><button onclick="delete("ID'.$ID.')" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="deleteBtn">Delete</button></td></tr>';

    }
```

Now you can Id like this:-

```
$('button#deleteBtn').click( function(){
    data = $(this).parents('tr').data('id');
    alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you have more than 1 row, you'll inevitably end up with a number of elements with the same ID. A cleaner up version would be:

More easily, you can simply use `.closest()`

**PHP:**

```
echo '<tr id='.$ID.'><td style="display:none;"><p id="ID">' . $ID . ' </p></td><td>' . $res['NAME'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $res['option2'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $res['Option3'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $res['Option4'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $res['Option5'] . '</td>
        <td class="deleteBtn"><button class="delete btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button></td></tr>'
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('button.delete').click( function(){
    var toDelete = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    alert(toDelete);
});
```